# DIv Is Overlapping With Another Div

Tags: html, css

i have have 3 section in my site all are working fine but when i creating another section4 it overlapping with section3 please check my code i want section4 display below the section3 i tried my best but nothing happen

css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 777;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section3{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.section4{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5312;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<Script type ="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="slider-main">
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <div class="cycle-pager">

    </div>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="section3">

</div>
<div class="section4">

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `position: absolute;` from section3,section4 thats why it's being overlaped by section4 .Hope It helps.

```css
 .site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section3{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.section3 p{
background-color:white;

}

.section4 p{
background-color:white;

}

.section4{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5312;
    overflow: hidden;
   
 background-color:blue;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="slider-main">
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <div class="cycle-pager">

    </div>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="section3">
<p>Section 3</p>
</div>
<div class="section4">
<p>section4</p>
</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but can you not just remove the css position: absolute on .section3 and .section4? The position absolute is making them overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.section3` and `.section4`

Your css code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 777;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section3{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.section4{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5312;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```